# How to mention shadowing and fading in wireless channel model?

Tags: matlab, channel, cellular-network

I am trying to model a wireless channel with following parameters in matlab.

Multipath Fading: Exponential distribution with unit mean

Shadowing: Log-normal distribution with standard deviation 8 dB

Path-loss exponent: 2.4

Path-loss constant: 30

How should I mention shadowing and fading in the channel model in dB?
I tried to use log-normal and exponential distributions in matlab to generate random numbers with given parameters. But I am not sure if it is true or not.
Can anyone help me?

(There is a similar question in [Sjaffry question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275481/wireless-channel-model-for-beacon-transmission-in-matlab-w-path-loss-shadowing), but it doesn't have any answer and because I don't have enough reputation to comment on that topic, I tried to ask my own question.)

More Information:

I know that:

```
g_i,j = 10log10(K) - 10log10(B) - 10log10(T) -10alog10(L_i,j);
```

Where `g_i,j` is channel gain, `B` is fading gain, `T` is shadowing gain, `L_i,j` is distance between i , j and `K` is path loss constant.
I wrote this code in matlab:

```
k = 30;
a = 2.4;
T = 8; % dB
Distance = Dist([i_x, i_y], [j_x,j_y]);
 G_dB = 10*log10(k) - 10*log10(exprnd(1)) - 10*log10(random('logn', 0 , (10^(T/10)))) -10 * a * log10(Distance);
```

The channel gain values (for distances about 300 m) must be more than one or less than one?

Comment: Your approach seems correct. However, take into account that, regarding shadowing, the standard deviation given usually refers to the associated Gaussian distribution (that is, shadowing in dB), not to the log-normal distribution (shadowing in natural units). Anyway, to get more help you should post the relevant part of your code. Also, questions like "is this correct?" do not tend to get good answers. You better explain exactly where you got stuck

Comment: @LuisMendo, Thanks for your explanation. I add the part of code that I use to calculate channel gain.